# Tramp: killing all buffers

Tags: tramp

Whenever I use ssh over Tramp to get to my local server (either with dired or pointing directly to a file), another buffer is also created:

```
#<buffer *tramp/ssh user@local_server_address*>
```

When I finished my editing and close the buffer I was working on, the above mentioned buffer remains. Since it is not useful to me, is there a way to automatically kill it when I finished my editing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get rid of these buffers with `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections`.

Comment: That does not kill the buffers. `tramp-cleanup-all-buffers` does.